# Performance in CSS hierarchy

Tags: css, performance

If I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="inner">
   </div>
</div>
```

Is there any difference , performance wise, between:

```
#container #inner {
      width:300px;
}
```

to

```
#inner {
      width:300px;
}
```

?

Comment: Not sure about performance, but nesting ID selectors is almost always pointless.

Comment: true, I should've used class instead. thanks!

Comment: http://screwlewse.com/2010/08/different-css-techniques-and-their-performance/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wont really affect it,

just CSS selectors with a wide-matching key selector can hurt performance ..

some insight here: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/06/18/simplifying-css-selectors/

Comment: If I understand correctly from the article, in a page where I have many anchor tags, it will be better to give each a class/id and select it by #container a#ID {} than #container a {} ?

Comment: @ joel : i believe thats the implication. though it'd be simpler to use #ID {} instead of #container a#ID {}

Answer (score 3):

The performance difference will be inconsequential. Try optimizing other parts of your code!

That being said, it's generally best to be as non-specific as possible.

Answer (score 1):

As `id`s aren't supposed to repeat, you can simply select using `#inner`